# PHP add data-visible on if condition

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using Boot Grid table on a project and I only want to show specific columns depending on the account type.

The approach I wanted to take is to use PHP on an if statement:

If account_type = "Rep" make ID#name data-visible="false"

```
<th data-column-id="name" data-visible="true">Name</th>

  if($_SESSION['account_type'] === 'Rep') {
    echo '$("#name").attr("data-visible", "false");';
  }
```

Is this possible with PHP or will I have to use jQuery?
If I use jQuery, this isn't going to be that secure right?

I'm a beginner, so I'm trying to find the simplest solution.

Comment: That should work. But you don't have script tags around the JS

Comment: whats the right syntax to wrap the script tags?  echo '<script>'$("#name").attr("data-visible", "false");'</script>';  ?

Comment: Yep that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing is keep the value in hidden element.And use it in the javascript.

```
<th data-column-id="name" data-visible="true">Name<input type='hidden' name='account_type' id='account_type' value='<?=$_SESSION['account_type']?>'></th>
```

Then

```
<script>
$(function(){
var account_type=$('#account_type').val();
  if(account_type === 'Rep') {
    $("#name").attr("data-visible", "false");
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible with PHP or will I have to use jQuery?
>   If I use jQuery, this isn't going to be that secure right?

If you can compare the `account_type` on PHP side...

Then why not just use it to fill (or not fill) the `td` content?

```
if($_SESSION['account_type'] === 'Rep') {
  <th data-column-id="name">Name</th>
}else{
  <th data-column-id="name"></th>    // Empty!
}
```

**If it needs to be secure...** The best way is not to send the info.
You can even not send the whole column!
Just also apply this to the `td` of all rows.

A `hidden input` can be found in console and "sniffed" by scripts.

Comment: This is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if statement Try this solution. Hope it helps!

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('#name').prop('data-visible', 'false');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add script,css and php files are in separate pages.